# how to implement ajax-request processing using wt?

Tags: c++, json, rest, wt

I send json to url localhost/json. how can I process this request? how is it perfoming at all? Is it necessery implement my own WResource, WServer, WApplication and something else?
Please explain me, how works with it using Wt.

```
/* in LoginForm() */
...
client.done().connect(this, &LoginForm::receiveJSONresponse);
...


void LoginForm::sendLogInRequest()
{
    Json::Object data;
    data["action"] = "login";
    data["username"] = usernameTextEdit.text();
    data["password"] = passwordTextEdit.text(); 
    Http::Message msg;
    msg.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    msg.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    msg.addBodyText(Json::serialize(data));
    client.request(Http::Post, "http://localhost/json", msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specialize a WResource, and in handleRequest() look at the data that was posted.

WResource has two ways to be used: either session-specific or global. A session-specific resource has a random URL, while a global resource has a specified (constant) URL.

For what you ask, to attach the resource to localhost/json, the resource has to be attached to a fixed URL, so indeed you do this through the WServer API. Take a look at the blog example to see how the BlogRSSFeed is deployed as static resource. You can use this as a start point and modify handleRequest to process the json posted to the resource.